# How to exit recovery mode loop on an android phone used for development?

Tags: android

so i was messing with second screen app for changing resolution while mirroring
and i installed adb and added:

```
 adb shell pm grant com.farmerbb.secondscreen.free android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

and as soon as i started second screen my phone went into recovery mode and stuck in a loop where i have three options:

1-connect with mi assistant (which the software doesn't recognize my phone)

2-wipe Data but considering the fact that i haven't backup phone and i have some important data it's just impossible for me

3-is the reboot option which gets interesting cause when my phone is in this mode my device is shown in adb devices

```
List of devices attached
68100cf8        device
```

and seems like i have full access (i'm not sure)

so My Question is: is it possible to recover my data with adb or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

in recovery mode, the adb also can be used, you can pull data from data partition if it mounted.